# as.Date(ww-yyyy) in R

Tags: r, date, as.date

I have an Excel-file with a lot of dates in the format "ww-yyyy". When it is loaded into R it is seen as "42370" (for instance).
I need to extract the week and year for each data point `x`.
I have tried `as.POSIXct`,`as.POSIXlt, as.Date(x, format="%w-%y,origin = 1899-12-30)`.

`as.Date(42370,format =%w%y)` gives the output "2023-11-14" which should've been week 53 in 2015

Comment: how did you read the excel file into R? It might be easier to read the column as text and convert from there.

Comment: Convert to date and then format to desire format like with this: `format(as.Date(42370, origin = "1899-12-30"), "%W-%Y")`

Comment: @Dave2e is there a way to convert the `%W-%Y` to date format? like this it's a character!

Comment: If it is a character string then `as.Date("04-2020", %W-%Y)` should work.  See `?strptime` for a list of all of the date and time formats.